# Is my impact driver normal?

Tags: powertools, screwdriver

I recently purchased a reconditioned impact driver from Bosch and everything is good except one bothering thing. When I try to countersink a screw, the clutch kicks in right before the screw head enters the surface. Then, to push it further, I have to keep pulling the trigger to force it to move foward, which makes the screw move slowly with the continuous clicking sound (due to the clutch). Unlike my drill driver, this impact driver does not have the no-clutch setting.

Because I purchased a reconditioned one, I am wondering if this behavor is normal or any mechanical failure.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the first time you've used an impact driver? They sound and feel very different. The clicking / banging you hear is not the clutch, it is the hammer mechanism striking inside the tool. (Does your impact driver even have an adjustable clutch? It is not common on impact tools.)

Comment: You're right. This is the first time of using it. Based on the experience with my drill driver, I just assumed that the clicking sound was coming from the clutching. My impact driver has three speed/torque settings.

Answer (score 2):

As the force increases the driver starts impacting this is normal.
If you want to test it out get a larger screw you will notice it may start impacting much sooner.
I find I can drive 2-3 times as many screws with my impact driver than with my drill (using the same size battery).
The impact driver is also ~ ½ the weight of the drill. Also I think I can control the depth better because of the very slight pause between hits.

Comment: Thank you!  I now understand why it is called an "impact driver" :)